# Is there any C compiler which defines both __STDC__ and __STDC_IEC_559__ to 1?

Tags: c, compiler

Is there any C compiler(s) which defines both `__STDC__` and `__STDC_IEC_559__` to 1?

If so, then which one(s)?

Reason of the question: as far as I can test (April 2021), none of the latest versions of popular C compilers (gcc, clang, msvc) define both `__STDC__` and `__STDC_IEC_559__` to 1. Hence, these compilers may generate executable files, which produce non-IEEE 754 conformant results. However, there is a demand on such C compilers, which actually provide a guarantee / confidence that generated executable files produce IEEE 754 conformant results (under strict floating-point model option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the definition of `__STDC_IEC_559__` depends on the host:

```
Compiler   Host       __STDC_IEC_559__
gcc        Windows    0
clang      Windows    0
gcc        Linux      1
clang      Linux      1
```